# Answer deleted without cause, should it be flagged for modderator attention?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I was just digging through my old stuff and noticed I had one of my answers deleted(three votes by non-moderators). However it does not come close to violating any of the rules for deletion listed on https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

> commentary on the question or other answers
>
> asking another, different question
>
> “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
>
> exact duplicates of other answers
>
> barely more than a link to an external site
>
> not even a partial answer to the actual question

Should I flag my own post, "...for serious problems or moderator attention" to get it reinstated?

It was on topic, answered the question as accurate as practical (the Q is on the edge of "overly broad"), factual, fairly complete without being a semester in college, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I flag my own post, "...for serious problems or moderator attention" to get it reinstated?

well, you opened a meta post, in this case it is a bit pointless to also flag the post.

> It was on topic, answered the question as accurate as practical (the Q is on the edge of "overly broad")

Well, there you have your problem. Instead of answering broadly, you should have helped the asker to refine the question to make it less broad, *and then* answer.

I looked at that answer of yours, and while I might not have deleted it, I don't see any value in it to justify bringing it back now, as it basically it is a comment to the asker telling them "your question is broad, and a precise answer cannot be given".

What you can do is to discuss the question with the asker in chat or here on meta to try make it less broad (if there is enough consensus that it is indeed broad), and then answer.

Alternatively you could make some reasonable assumptions, state them in the answer, and give a more specific answer, maybe with some numbers and confidence ranges.